# Why does display: block solve so many web design problems?

Tags: html, css

As a novice web designer I have found that the answer to so many web design problems (content not showing up, alignment being incorrect, sizes not working properly, positioning not working properly, etc) often seems to be display: block or display: inline-block.

Why is this? I find it frustrating. I will be working on something that isn't working for 5 minutes to half an hour only to find out the answer is display: block... once again.

Comment: Are you running any custom style scripts like Bootstrap? They may be overriding the `<div>` display value, which should be `block` by default. Are you using `<span>`s? Their default is `inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All html elements have a default display type, which are usually block or inline.

inline elements do not have a height or width property, so their behaviour in the DOM can be less intuitive than block or inline-block elements.

> block elements start on a new line and take up the whole width.
>
> inline-block elements are formatted like inline elements, but have a
>   height and width property.

You can read more about it here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: That makes sense, I never thought to look up the different behavioral properties of the display types. I also didn't realize that different elements have different default display types. I feel like I've reached the next (very low) plateau in my web design understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Further things to consider. Inline elements can only contain other inline elements, so if you have a parent element set as inline with a child element set as block the child's height and width won't be acknowledged by the parent.

Comment: Please add a more complete answer if you feel its necessary @Temani

Comment: to answer what question? ... is the question clear/precise? And how what you said explain/answer the *too broad* question? ... by giving the definition of display:block you explained why it solve magically all the issues?

Comment: Perhaps you should mark the question and the answer as to broad or off topic then? I just tried to answer the question concisely and in a way that would make sense to me.

Comment: That's good to know @RowanBaker-French. I have sometimes wondered why child elements don't inherit their parent's sizes.